# Create instance of generic class from a dynamic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

Is it possible to create a instance of generic class whose type is derived dynamically.

```cs
Class GenericClass<T> {

}

Main()
{
    string inputtype = "classname, assemblyname";

    Type type = Type.GetType(inputtype);

    dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // Want to create a object of GenericClass<T> but I get compiletime errors.
    // Is it possible to do like below?

    GenericClass<instance> = new GenericClass<instance>();
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, using reflection. But as a general rule if you' don't know the generic type at compiletime, you're probably using generics wrong or don't really want generics.

Answer (score 7):

You can use reflection like this:

```cs
object genericInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(type));
```

but then you'd have to cast it to make any use of it so it's not type-safe.

Comment: Since `MakeGenericType` takes a `params Type[]` you can just do `MakeGenericType(type)`.

Comment: I am able to create instance now, but public methods are not accessible now

Comment: They won't be accessible unless you cast the object to something that exposes public methods - cf Jamiec answer to that regard.

Comment: Can I invoke the public methods also dynamically using reflection?

Comment: yes, have a look at [Type.GetMethods()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?view=netframework-4.8). Without more context from you, that looks like a dodgy move though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can instantiate a generic type at runtime, knowing the generic type(s) parameters it expects. Can you do anything useful with it? That depends.

Here's an example. Note that I have a (non-generic) interface which gives me a behaviour I can use:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var genericType = typeof(int); // You could have a string and Type.GetType here
        var genericClassType = typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(genericType);
        var instance = (ICanTellYouMyType)Activator.CreateInstance(genericClassType);
        Console.WriteLine(instance.WhatsMyGenericType()); 
        // Output is "Int32"

    }
}

public interface ICanTellYouMyType
{
    string WhatsMyGenericType();
}

public class GenericClass<T> : ICanTellYouMyType
{
    public string WhatsMyGenericType()
    {
        return typeof(T).Name;
    }
}
```

Live example: https://rextester.com/XJHFM53278

Comment: I am able to create instance now, but public methods are not accessible now.

Comment: @phanish thats my point about whether it is useful to do this. You cant access that object without casting to it, and you cant do that unless you know they type at compile time - unless you have a common interface as per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are not actually answering your question which is:

> Can I do this: `GenericClass<instance> = new GenericClass<instance>();`?

No you can't. As other answers explain, you can create a generic object with types only known at runtime through reflection but you can not leverage any kind of type information of the object you've just created at compile time.

¿How could you, if its only known at runtime? And if its not only known at runtime, then you wouldn't be in this mess to begin with; you'd sepcify an assignable type at compile time (in your code).

Generics, is a red herring here. Your problem is basically not knowing the type of an object when writing the code:

```
Type t = someMethodGivesMeATypeIDontKnowWhenWritingThisCode();

//I need to make an instance of this type.
//The only thing I know is that it needs to have a default contructor
//or it will crash
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

What do you think the compile time of `o` will be? It can't be anything else than `object` because the compiler doesn't and can't know anything about the real type of the object.

Comment: Can I invoke the public methods also dynamically using reflection?

Comment: @phanish Yes, if you know the signature of the methods you want to call. You can also use dynamic and make the code easier to write/read.